# Get current value from grouped tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

so, I grouped my tablix by an ID and make page breaks for every different ID.
How can I know which value the ID on the current site have and how can I use it in expressions (I don't want to use the value in the same tablix where I grouped, I want to use the it for a textbox and a diagram.

I can't find any solution in the internet, maybe you have some ideas.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use subreports.

Answer (score 1):

How would you manage to put an image and/or textbox on each page, when your tablix is page breaking on an instance of your grouping? You must remember that the full tablix output, along with all instances, will first show before any other image or textbox is displayed after.

You would need to have the image/textbox in the table and within the grouping. This would actually solve your problem.

While i dont think this is what you are looking for, I believe its the only way to get around this. Or as Tab Allerman suggested you could use sub reports.